# Сохранение полного пути текущей директории в переменную

Tags: postgresql

Как в postgresql в sql-скрипте сохранить полный путь текущей рабочей директории в переменную или в таблицу?
Знаю, как вывести на экран('! pwd'), но не знаю, как сохранить этот полный путь.

Comment: Это русский StackOverflow. Задайте вопрос на русском языке :)

Answer (score 2):

Все-таки удалось самому придумать. Ниже код

```
DROP TABLE tbl_pwd;
CREATE TABLE tbl_pwd(
    pwd TEXT
);

\COPY tbl_pwd FROM PROGRAM 'pwd';
SELECT * FROM tbl_pwd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если под юниксом, то вот так можно:

```
postgres=# \! pwd
/home/postgres

postgres=# \set dir `pwd`
postgres=# \echo :dir
/home/postgres
```

Вот что говорит на эту тему документация ([по-русски](http://postgrespro.ru/doc/app-psql.html), [по-английски](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html)):

> Метакоманды
>
> ...
>
> Текст аргумента, заключённый в обратные кавычки (`), считается
>   командной строкой, которая передаётся в командную оболочку ОС. Вывод
>   от этой команды (с удалёнными в конце символами новой строки) заменяет
>   текст в обратных кавычках.